# It does not find my image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
                Image icon = null;

                if (/* some logic test that succeeds*/)
                {
                    icon = new Image();
                    icon.Width = 32;
                    icon.Height = 32;
                    icon.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
                    icon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/icons/flower.png", UriKind.Relative)); ;
                    icon.IsHitTestVisible = false;
                }

                if (icon != null)
                    MyCanvas.Children.Add(icon);
```

I dont know why this fails. I store my image as content in the Images/Icons folder in the project. Still after the I've set the source (.Source above) the PixelHeight and Width is 0 of the source.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Your source path is probably bad.

Comment: Are you sure your Uri shouldn't be "Images/icons/flower.png"? That's assuming that what you're running is actually in the same folder as Images. If not, you'll need to edit your Uri to be relative to your actual executable.

Comment: @Mike Precup i checked the .xap file archive. The Image/icons folder is in the xap. Ive tried "/Images/.." and "Images/..." with no luck

Comment: Is the `BuildAction` property of the image set to `Content`?